# Add or remove listeners to listenMulticast at runtime in twisted?

Tags: python, udp, twisted, master-slave, reactor

The title pretty much explains it;

Is it possible? I want to create a master-backup relationship where if the master fails, the backup takes over, becomes the master and creates its own backup and keeps running. I'm using `listenMulticast` to broadcast so far.

I want a behavior where I print increasing numbers in the terminal for learning purposes. If I send some sort of a interrupt signal, the master should be destroyed but from above, the relationship is re-created and the numbers keeps printing. For this purpose, I don't care if a numbers is skipped, I'm simply after the structure.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`reactor.listenMulticast`](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.interfaces.IReactorMulticast.html#listenMulticast) returns an [`IListeningPort`](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.interfaces.IListeningPort.html).  [`IListeningPort.stopListening`](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.interfaces.IListeningPort.html#stopListening) stops the port from listening.  [`IListeningPort.startListening`](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.interfaces.IListeningPort.html#startListening) starts it listening at the same address again.

You can call `listenMulticast`, `stopListening`, or `startListening` at any time.

Comment: Maybe `twisted` isn't suited for my purpose. I might as well just use the `socket` library with threads and hope I can get the behavior I want. The plan was that I could destroy the `DatagramProtocol` object and recreate it, as if one of my clients/servers actually crashed. Thanks.

Comment: I'm sure I can't comment on details of your application of which I am unaware.